# Difference between BOs and Services?

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I'm designing a shopping cart web application in Java.

Many Java applications seem to adopt the same naming conventions which I would like to use.

For instance:

- ***_*** - entity which is persisted to database
- **___DAO** - DAO which provides CRUD methods for persisting Item to database
- **___BO**  - I've only seen these used as a thin wrapper around DAOs. Is there any other point to these?
- **___Service** - Used to expose API?

How do most designers split code between BO and Service?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using EJBs I think there is a little confusion. Your objects you are naming "entity" objects are the Business Objects. In a POJO based application BOs represent the domain. Take a look at this sample project: [Spring's Pet Store](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/trunk/samples/jpetstore/src/org/springframework/samples/jpetstore/).

The "**domain**" directory contains the BOs.
Note that there is a "**service**" and a "**dao**" directory, which obviously contain the respective services and DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use DAOs in service directly (no BOs) and point of service layer is to add caching, transactional stuff like thing also you could easily expose them as webservice if required